# MATLAB: linear regression of a generic multivariate polynomial to data

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

I would like to fit a multivariate polynomial of arbitrary degree to my data using MATLAB. Suppose I have two variables, and I use a polynomial of degree two: my polynomial is thus y=c1+c2*x1+c3*x2+c4x1*x2+c5*x1+c6*x2. Also suppose I have n observations and

```
X = [X1 X2]
```

is the matrix storing the (x1,x2) couples for each observation.

One possibility would be to use

```
C=A\Y
```

where Y is the vector of responses corresponding to each observation (x1,x2), and A is the matrix

```
A=[ones(n,1) X1 X2 X1.*X2 X1.^2 X2.^2]
```

However, this is not generic at all, and I have to write an expression for A by hand, each time I modify the number of variables or the degree of the polynomial. Ideally, I would need some nice 'bsxfun' trick :) otherwise, "ugly" for loops will do.

Alternatively, I may use 'fitlm', to which I have access:

```
 LM = fitlm(DS,MODELSPEC)
```

From the help, I understand that DS is a dataset containing my observations (x1,x2,...,xn,y). However, MODELSPEC should be "a T-by-V matrix where T is the desired number of terms in the model and V is the number of variables in DS. The (I,J) element indicates the power of variable J in term I." I don't know how to write a generic MODELSPEC for arbitrary degree and number of variables. Can you help me?

EDIT: the example used a degree 2 polynomial in two variables just for the sake of brevity. I'm looking for a solution which works for polynomials of degree *n* in *m* variables, where *n* and *m* are arbitrary.

Comment: Have you tried searching the fileexchange? I found this [submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34918-multivariate-polynomial-regression).

Comment: If you have access to the Curve Fitting Toolbox, `cftool` is your friend.

Comment: @DaveKielpinski, `cftool` works for at most two predictors (independent variables). I need something which works for an arbitrary number of predictors. I made an example with two variables just for the sake of brevity.

Comment: @knedlsepp thanks a lot for the pointer. I thought this problem could be solved with a few lines of code, but maybe I underestimated its difficulty, because the code you refer to is very complex (for me). However, it does work for any number of variables, and any degree of the polynomial, which is absolutely great. According to its documentation, the only issue I can see is that evaluating the fitted polynomial (i.e., making predictions) is very cumbersome. I will test the code Monday and let you know.

Comment: Sorry DeltaIV. I misread your question.

Comment: no problem @DaveKielpinksi. Thanks for the interest in the question, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is not the solution I was looking for, so if anyone wants to try his/her hand at answering, please do :) But still, I hope it can be of help to anybody having my same problem! I found this file on MATLAB Central:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34765-polyfitn

It's similar to the link by @knedlsepp, but, according to the documentation, prediction (i.e., evaluation of the fitted model at test points not included in the fitting data) looks simpler and more flexible.